# Problem running pcor.test (partial correlation)

Tags: r, correlation

This is the dput for my dataset:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021"), Month_Number = c("8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9"), Month_Name = c("August", "August", "August", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
"September", "September", "September"), Day_Number = c(29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L), Day_Name = c("Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"), Time_Wake = c(730L, 800L, 730L, 500L, 
715L, 600L, 600L, 700L, 600L, 700L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 700L, 
645L, 700L, 630L, 645L, 700L, 600L, 700L), Start_Work = c(1400L, 
1100L, 930L, 1015L, 1000L, 945L, 1400L, 1500L, 915L, 930L, 1000L, 
940L, 840L, 730L, 1700L, 945L, 1040L, 955L, 945L, 930L, 745L, 
800L), End_Work = c(1900L, 1755L, 1520L, 1800L, 1600L, 1210L, 
1700L, 1515L, 1530L, 1530L, 1800L, 1650L, 1800L, 1410L, 2000L, 
1710L, 1430L, 1800L, 1840L, 1720L, 1915L, NA), Mins_Sleep = c(420L, 
360L, 360L, 300L, 540L, 540L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 420L, 300L, 
240L, 480L, 300L, 420L, 360L, 390L, 405L, 420L, 360L, 420L), 
    Workout_Y_N = c("N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", 
    ""), Time_Workout = c(NA, NA, NA, 730L, 730L, 730L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 730L, 730L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 735L, 735L, 735L, NA, 
    NA, NA), Work_Environment = c("Home", "Office", "Office", 
    "Office", "Office", "Office", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", 
    "Office", "Office", "Office", "Home", "Home", "Office", "Office", 
    "Office", "Home", "Office", "Home", "Home"), Coffee_Cups = c(4L, 
    0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Tea_Cups = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L), Mins_Work = c(300L, 420L, 310L, 435L, 350L, 145L, 
    135L, 15L, 60L, 60L, 390L, 395L, 395L, 315L, 80L, 580L, 175L, 
    545L, 230L, 435L, 370L, NA), Onset_Mood = c("Tired", "Tired", 
    "Sad", "Angry", "Rested", "Rested", "Rested", "Tired", "Tired", 
    "Tired", "Rested", "Angry", "Tired", "Rested", "Angry", "Angry", 
    "Angry", "Sad", "Rested", "Sad", "Tired", "Tired")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

I'm simply trying to run a partial correlation between the variables "`Coffee_Cups`" and "`Mins_Work`" controlled by "`Day_Name`". However, when I run this partial correlation from the ppcor library:

```
library(ppcor)    
pcor.test(x=work$Mins_Work,
              y=work$Coffee_Cups,
              z=work$Day_Name)
```

It gives me this error:

> Error in pcor(xyz, method = method) : 'x' 必需是数值 # (Chinese = "Needs to be a numeric value")

I tried switching the x and y variables, but that didn't seem to have an impact either, despite both being numerical values. Is there something I'm potentially doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks that `z` also need to be numeric

Comment: I tried that with this code: `pcor.test(x=work$Mins_Work, y=work$Coffee_Cups, z=work$Tea_Cups)` but even with three numerics I get this error: __Error in if (det(cvx) < .Machine$double.eps) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for `pcor.test`, it says `Missing values are not allowed`. The variable `Mins_Work` has a missing value `NA`.

```
work$Mins_Work
 [1] 300 420 310 435 350 145 135  15  60  60 390 395 395 315  80 580 175 545 230 435 370  NA
```

Furthermore all the variable need to be numeric but the variable `Day_Name` isn't.

```
work$Day_Name
 [1] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday" 
[13] "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"
```

Comment: Ah didnt notice there was an NA in there. But as I mentioned in another comment, I tried this with the Tea_Cups variable (which is numeric) and still had the same issue when I replaced Day_Name with it.

Comment: Ah I think I just fixed it! Looks like when I removed both the NA and switched it out for a numeric, it finally worked. Thanks stranger!